# How can I manually trigger a single job in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a simple Azure Pipeline containing two stages:

- Stage 1: Build
- Stage 2: Run tests

Stage 1 builds the source code and pushes the binaries to Azure Artifacts. Stage 2 downloads the binaries of Stage 1 and runs multiple tests against them, using different jobs for different tests:

- Job 1: Run tests for module A
- Job 2: Run tests for module B
- Job 3: Run tests for module C

These jobs are completely indepent of each other and run in parallel.

If all stages and jobs succeed, **how can I manually trigger Job 3** in Stage 2 without triggering Stage 1 and Job 1 and 2 of Stage 2 again?

One ugly work around might be to use variables and somehow run a new pipeline, skip stage 1 if the variables are set and download the binaries from a previous pipeline. Are there better approaches?

Edit: There is a similar topic ongoing on ms dev community:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/697467/manually-triggered-stages-in-yaml-multi-stage-pipe.html?childToView=903723#comment-903723

Comment: No, seems not to be possible at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you are after with [multi-stage pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops) if you pull the individual Jobs that exist in your current Stage 2 up into their own independent Stages.

Once you do that, you can then manually trigger them independently for reruns.
[image]

Or if you had a need, you can also start a new run with only a subset of the stages.
[image]

Comment: While I kind of like the idea, this seems more than a workaround. Aren't stages supposed to run one after another? Because I want to be able to run the tests in parallel.

Comment: Ah I saw now its possible to run stages in parallel:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

However, it still feels like a workaround since conceptually wise stages should run on after another I guess.

Comment: Stages are the smallest atomic body of work that you can rerun on demand manually. And yes you can run them in parallel. But I guess you might be after something slightly different based on your edit link.

Answer (score 0):

If you define release pipeline in yaml , you can through adding `condition: false` to disable/skip a job in multiple-job pipeline.

```
- job: Foo  
  condition: false
```

For details , you can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/393253/add-support-to-temporarily-disableskip-a-job-in-mu.html).

Then you can choose which stages to run when running multi-stages pipeline ,through this, you can skip Stage1.

[image]

Comment: Thats not what I want basically. I want to be able to trigger single jobs like in GitLab.